# Angular - two components communicating with each other

Tags: angularjs

I'm still trying to understand bindings in Angular and I come with a strong jQuery background, so perhaps I'm totally in the wrong here, but I want to make a `component` that other components will have access to and will be able to invoke its functions.

For this, I've made an example:

```
app.component('shadow', {
    bindings: {
        colour: '@'
    },
    controller: function() {
            this.setColour = setColour;

            function setColour(colour) {
                    this.colour = colour;
            }
    },
    template: ['<div ',
        'style="background: {{ $ctrl.colour }}; width: 100px; height: 100px;">',
        '<button ng-click="$ctrl.setColour(\'red\');">Button</button>',
        '<button ng-click="noise.music()">Noise</button>',
    '</div>'].join('')
});

app.component('noise', {
    bindings: {
        name: '='
    },
    controllerAs: 'noise',
    controller: function() {
        this.name = 'Noise';
        this.music = music;

        function music() {
            alert('Merzbow');
        }
    },
    template: ['<div>{{ noise.name }}</div>'].join('')
});
```

As you can see, I created one component named `shadow` and one named `noise` (pun intened). What I want now is to access one directive from another. They are not associated with each other whatsoever.

Comment: Would you mind adding this to a plunkr? Or a codepen?

Comment: More information on the possible use is required. Do they have to have parent/children relationship? How do you expect this to behave when there are multiple 'noise' elements?

Comment: You can use http://codepen.io/TheLarkInn/pen/zrRKGJ/ my angular 1.5 codepen template if youd like to create this.

Comment: Also will these two `components` always accompany eachother?

Comment: Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/MKQaej

Comment: From the docs COMPONENT INTERACTION: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-setter

Comment: @JaredChristensen, my question it about A1 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create components which will communicate with each other you should create services, not directives. Directive is a component mostly for part of html, or for usage as an attribute on `html` elements

In all cases, its does not metter what are you using (directives or services) you have to `inject` one into another so then you can call injected component' methods

**UPDATE**

How to inject something into something in angular? Using angular dependency injector! Bingo! How to inject? First variant (you specify dependency in component file):

```
var component = function($scope) {
    // your component code here
};

component.$inject = ["$scope"]
```

Second variant (you specify dependency during registration component):

```
var component = function($scope) {
    // your component code here
};

angular.module("yourModule").component("componentName", ["$scope", component]);
```

How to manipulate the DOM with service? Look, if you really want to work with angular you should forget about jquery principles. There is no need to manipulating the DOM directly from somewhere. You create you view (which could be also a directive), your view has a specified with it controller, you place your addition functionality in services. **Thats it!** Angular will do all the rest for you. You want display something from server? No problems, call your server, and show that data on your view. How? Just assign it to scope and then populate from that on your view. You want to have some helpers? You can do it with services! Again, forget about jquery and direct DOM manipulation. You work with MVVM framework which based on MVC pattern.

P.S. If want to really understand how angular works look at the angular [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). It explains well how to cook angular application

Comment: My current idea is to create somethiing as a loading indicator, so I would have to manipulate the DOM. From what I found out, directives and/or components are made for this.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski, Yes you are right, directive is for manipulating the DOM. But by manipulating in angular it means generating part of html. If you want to get some additional data create a service for it, inject it in directive and use. OR you can do this in directives controller if you want

Comment: Any idea, how can I `inject` anything into `component`? Also, how can I create a service that would create additional HTML? `document.innerHTML` etc?

Comment: component injection doesn't work like that: `.component("componentName", ["$scope", component])`. It is component's controller that needs to be injected, not a component.

Comment: @estus, yes my fault. but it was just for simplicity. I prefer to use `factory`, `directive`, `filter` methods instead

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a factory and you include this factory in the both modules. After that, everything in the factory will be shared between the components.